# PHP session breaks after clicking link to new page that includes config

Tags: php, html, session, nginx

When `$_SESSION` is set, under simple pages things work fine, but any page that includes `inc/config.php` will instantly break that session and return back to an empty array. Accessing the page by manually typing the URL in does NOT break this session, this only happens when clicking a link to that page (ie: `<a href="some-page.php">Link</a>`).

So for instance, if I'm logged in and am on the Homepage (`index.php`), which does not have the config included, everything will work fine. But if I click a link in the navbar to `about.php` which does include the config, my session will be broken and I need to login again.

I have spent **hours** trying to figure this out, so any help would be greatly appreciated. **There are no errors or warnings.**

**PHP Version:** PHP 5.5.9 (`php5-fpm` for `nginx`)

#### Session Generation

```
/* Start PHP session if none exists */
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();

    /* 1/5 chance to regenerate ID */
    if (mt_rand(0, 4) === 0) {
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
}
```

Session are generated using the following code above on any page that requires it. (ie: `inc/navigation.php` which uses the session to change login/logout links.)

#### inc/config.php

```
<?php
    /* Global Salts/Keys; Created with: https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ */
    define('AUTH_KEY',         't!tsg&n;>=C&!?rM[N=rIXGRc)$7+.yh{1x-W2#/ fZJZ(0647q&/G6ZIO,S}v(x');
    define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'm=b&8Xm!i:F3&U.{ajs}]5z10DjH_GV[w|6L=Rlwkosr4O:owE!`VS*-8ro%!3 2');
    define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '-krqegOl:}|C;~&r](wA4aB*t)XZ ow*luwt:s(VVR&xAy{Hh*|d`X;`- i*}%+6');
    define('NONCE_KEY',        'svR1:eGpNZ6>^g~-L@ 5K<8KqF3SW(R#OWwI^rL9ll)U3,63Q|{-%de&cUedX47Z');
    define('AUTH_SALT',        '+A!Aj7 Yk|8NWF-+7d,r7tB6+K(obe4AJd-=LGB6#H:} AQI+NQF|w53Eb5#.>Jo');
    define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'hiF_Vd;~XC-UU24c1(s&Q/:XXKTx$8W+Tv%Ed+ =CqS+_K@lW|DwRyk-wC(g5%%p');
    define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'q}{W~6(nOfJ(-diA>>K9gkpBq>H4D>d1FTWh|e)NxZe5Xp0H4+n.$*(l&l!G_9cY');
    define('NONCE_SALT',       ',.heuv{eZ) %+DwwmG,9RNybXNAo`FfAi:gR&0<#>-!7NA=)y)-_!qV$2C5R>rJo');

    /* MySQL Database Settings */
    define('SQL_TYPE',          'mysql');
    define('SQL_HOST',          'localhost');
    define('SQL_PORT',          '3306');
    define('SQL_DB',            'database');
    define('SQL_USER',          'username');
    define('SQL_PASSWD',        'password');

    /* Hashing Algorithm; See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php */
    define('HASH_FUNC',         'sha512');
?>
```

#### inc/navigation.php (example)

```
<?php
    /* Start PHP session if none exists */
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();

        /* 1/5 chance to regerate ID */
        if (mt_rand(0, 4) === 0) {
            session_regenerate_id(true);
        }
    }
?>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        .
        .
        .
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about.php">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Welcome, <?php echo isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user']['first_name'] : 'Guest'; ?> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) : ?>
                            <li><a href="/user.php">User Panel</a></li>
                            <?php if ($_SESSION['user']['level'] == 255) : ?>
                            <li><a href="/admin.php">Admin Panel</a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                        <?php else : ?>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Register</a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### about.php (example)

```
<?php
    /* Load configuration */
    require_once 'inc/config.php'; //This breaks the session
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <?php include 'inc/meta.php'; ?>
        <title>About :: CSU Clicker</title>

        <?php include 'inc/header.php'; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include 'inc/navigation.php'; ?>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <h1>Coming soon!</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php include 'inc/login-register.php'; ?>
        </div>

        <?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
        <?php include 'inc/notice.php'; ?>
        <?php include 'inc/error.php'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

`index.php` is the same as this, except there is no PHP block at the top.

#### php.ini

For the sake of not ruining this page, here's a link to my php.ini just in case you might need it: http://pastebin.com/gXELsEcu

Comment: Not sure if relevant but what server are you using?

Comment: @NijrajGelani Sorry, completely forgot about that. I'm using PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: $IAreKyleW00t you mean you're using PHP's development server?

Comment: How are you using $_SESSION? Can you provide an example? Maybe not calling session_start()?

Comment: @NijrajGelani I am using the latest one that was installed using `apt-get install php5-fpm` (using nginx).
@Naterade Apologizes, I forgot to include that information as well. I added how sessions are started/generated and an example page that uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was within my `php.ini` file. Having `session.referer_check` set to `1` caused the session to become invalid for some reason, so I left that option blank (which is what it was set to by default).

I have no idea why this would cause an issue, but it works.